# generate tensor like this in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Supposed I have a vector

```
[3, 2, 4]
```

I want to generate a corresponding tensor

```
[[1,1,1,0], [1,1,0,0],[1,1,1,1]]
```

Would you please tell us how to do this? Thanks

Comment: What is the problem you're having? Please post your code then we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.Session()

# Input tensor
indices = tf.placeholder_with_default([3, 2, 4], shape=(None,))

max_index = tf.reduce_max(indices)

def to_ones(index):
    ones = tf.ones((index, ), dtype=indices.dtype)
    zeros = tf.zeros((max_index - index, ), dtype=indices.dtype)
    return tf.concat([ones, zeros], axis=0)

# Output tensor
result = tf.map_fn(to_ones, indices)
```

`print(result)`:

```
Tensor("map/TensorArrayStack/TensorArrayGatherV3:0", shape=(?, ?), dtype=int32)
```

`print(sess.run(result))`:

```
[[1 1 1 0]
 [1 1 0 0]
 [1 1 1 1]]
```

`print(sess.run(result, feed_dict={indices: [1, 3, 3, 7]}))`:

```
[[1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 1 0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 1 0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1]]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you mind elaborating a little bit? I try to print out the variable ones and zeros in function to_ones but error occurs. I am still quite confused about what's going on inside the function.

Comment: `tf.map_fn` splits the `indices` into single numbers and passes each number to `to_ones`. The results of these `to_one` calls are then stacked to produce the final `result` tensor. So now the question is what the `to_ones` function does with a single number, passed via `index`. `tf.ones((index, ))` creates `index` ones in a row. For example `tf.ones((3, ))` will produce a tensor with `[1, 1, 1]`. Similarly, `tf.zeros((max_index - index, ))` creates `max_index - index` zeros in a row. By concatenating them together we ensure that every row returned by `to_ones` contains `max_index` elements.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that we only create a graph here, we don't actually create the ones themselves when we call `tf.ones((index, ))`. Thus, `print(...)` won't print the numbers. You can take a look here https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/graphs to learn more about graphs and sessions. If that way of computing seems counterintuitive, I recommend taking a look at eager execution https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/eager. There, your `print(...)` statements will work as intended.